# Git - Problems with Interactive Rebase and Squashing

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I know there are lots of questions on SO about this, but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for at all.

I just merged my task branch into my master, and I am ready to push my changes to the remote master branch.  However, they are displaying as two commits:

```
    commit 878c07412aab6a6b06b7fc8dd84c2418cc4f31d8
Merge: 9ffa590 c9f5552
Author: ***
Date:   Mon May 21 16:02:36 2012 +0100

    Merge branch 'modelUpdate4'

    Conflicts:
        ***.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

commit c9f5552862872673317701c3dffd7fb6b6daa02c
Author: ***
Date:   Mon May 21 15:03:21 2012 +0100

    Modified model according to requests.  Repopulated seeded database.
```

This is the output of git log and the two commits I wish to squash as one.  However, when I do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

It actually just displays 4 previously committed (and pushed) commits.  Am I misunderstanding how my branches are merged back?  If I try and git rebase -i   This just displays the first commit in the git log list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said four commits were already pushed, I'm guessing your graph (`git log --oneline --decorate --graph`) looks something like this, where you've got branching commits between `master` and `modelUpdate4` already pushed to the remote repo:

```
* (master, modelUpdate4, HEAD) Merge branch 'modelUpdate4'
| \
|  * (origin/modelUpdate4) Modified model according to requests. [HEAD^2]
|  |
|  * Another commit on modelUpdate4
|  |
|  * Yet another commit on modelUpdate4!
|  |
*  | (origin/master) Something that conflics with a commit in modelUpdate4 [HEAD~1]
| /
* Previous commit on master [HEAD~2]
```

`HEAD~2` is the first parent of the first parent, and since your `HEAD` is a merge of `modelUpdate4` into `master`, it refers to two commits down the `master` line. `HEAD^2` is `HEAD's` second parent, so the commit before `HEAD` down the `modelUpdate4` line. (See also: http://paulboxley.com/blog/2011/06/git-caret-and-tilde)

If `HEAD~2` is your new base, you'll get all the commits between `HEAD~2` and `master` in a straight line. You'll also have to deal with the branch conflict in the `modelUpdate4` commit where it happens.

```
* (master, HEAD) Merge branch 'modelUpdate4'
|
* Modified model according to requests.  Repopulated seeded database.
|
* Another commit on modelUpdate4
|
* Yet another commit on modelUpdate4!
|
* Something on master that conflics with modelUpdate4
|
* Previous commit on master
```

If anyone else is using those remote branches, or you want to maintain your branching history, don't rebase. It'll rewrite history that's already in the remote repo, which will just be a headache for everyone else. Push the merge commit out and you'll be golden.

Alternatively, you could rebase directly onto `origin/master`. `origin/modelUpdate4` would end up out in the git boonies, but since it's a task branch I'm betting you were just going to delete it anyway.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense! The graph is really helpful for understanding how HEAD~2 works now.